# converting Adobe AIR to Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

We have a Adobe AIR desktop client which talks to a WAMP server. How can i convert this AIR app to a Flex app to be used in the browser.
Please let me know.
Thanks
vish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a new empty Flex application and copy your files into that project.  Then move any code in your main app component (which is derived from WindowedApplication) into the main app component in your new project (which is derived from Application).  You'll also have to go through your app and determine which components are used that are specific to AIR and rework them to use other Flex components (the compiler will complain if you don't).  This should give you a good start.

Answer (score 4):

I would move everything into a Flex library project. Then have an AIR project as well as a Flex app project which accesses the common code in the Flex Library project. This way you don't have to maintain two different codebases for common code and you can also have code which is specific to each version.